# Predicting Missing Word in Sentence

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

How can I predict a word that's missing from a sentence?

I've seen many papers on predicting the *next word* in a sentence using an n-grams language model with frequency distributions from a set of training data. But instead I want to predict a missing word that's not necessarily at the end of the sentence. For example:

> I took my ___ for a walk.

I can't seem to find any algorithms that take advantage of the words after the blank; I guess I could ignore them, but they must add some value. And of course, a bi/trigram model doesn't work for predicting the first two words.

What algorithm/pattern should I use? Or is there no advantage to using the words after the blank?

Comment: Any of the algorithms you described should be adaptable, you just need to change the implementation slightly so it doesn't train exclusively on prior words. I'm not sure what you mean by "bi/trigram model doesn't work for predicting the first two words", but those methods should work just fine - you'd just have to change the patterns you're scanning the training data for, slightly.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll give it a try. What I meant was that if I'm using an algorithm that's based on the previous word, I can't predict the first word of the sentence (and if it's based on the previous two words, I can't predict the first two words); but I'm probably thinking about it wrong.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'll post an answer to clarify a bit more.

Comment: Well of course there is an advantage to using the following words. If you didn't use the following words then there's no way you could determine that "dog" would be an appropriate result and "boat" would be laughably wrong.

Comment: train two language models, one for left-to-right and one for right-to-left reads of your corpus. When a gap is given, call each language model where in one you condition the predictive probability on the stuff to the right, and on the other one you condition on the stuff to the left. Then take an average of the two probabilities and use it as your score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, when I've worked with bigrams/trigrams, an example query generally looked something like "Predict the missing word in 'Would you ____'". I'd then go through my training data and gather all the sets of three words matching that pattern, and count the things in the blanks. So, if my training data looked like:

```
would you not do that
would you kindly pull that lever
would you kindly push that button
could you kindly pull that lever
```

I would get two counts for "kindly" and one for "not", and I'd predict "kindly". All you have to do for your problem is consider the blank in a different place: "____ you kindly" would get two counts for "would" and one for "could", so you'd predict "would". As far as the computer is concerned, there's nothing special about the word order - you can describe whatever pattern you want, from your training data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 8):

Tensorflow has a tutorial to do this: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/word2vec/index.html

Incidentally it does a bit more and generates word embeddings, but to get there they train a model to predict the (next/missing) word. They also show using only the previous words, but you can apply the same ideas and add the words that follow.

They also have a bunch of suggestions on how to improve the precision (skip ngrams).

Somewhere at the bottom of the tutorial you have links to working source-code.

The only thing to be worried about is to have sufficient training data.

Comment: Can you please explain up until where I need to follow the code to predict the next missing word? I see they're creating the Skip Gram Model by saving the words that came before and after. However right after that they go to the Model Graph, which isn't what I think we need to predict words. Is that the right idea? Also do I need to manually save the context and words and invert them myself?